# TypeError: map is not function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, angular6

Estoy obteniendo datos de una api externa, en *resp* tengo toda la información de la api y me funciona perfectamente. De esta api me interesa especialmente el `['api-act']`. Por lo que, lo obtengo de la siguiente manera: `resp['api-act']` y lo almaceno.

Además, quiero obtener los 7 primeros valores (esto me funciona bien) y después me gustaría calcular el valor máximo, pero me da error.

Los valores q me devuelve la api son los siguientes:

```
 api-act: Array(31)
    >0:{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '0'}
    >1:{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '0'}
    >2:{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '0'}
    >3:{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '0'}
    >4:{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '0'}
    .....
    
    >30:{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '0'}
```

---

```
  this.servicioService.getData()
          .subscribe(resp => {
    
        this.act = resp['api-act'];
        for (let index = 0; index < this.act.length; index++) {
          if (index > 23 && index <= 30) {
            this.data = this.act[index];//Guardo los 7 primeros
            const maxValue = Math.max(...this.data.map(x => parseInt(x.value)))
            console.log(maxValue);
          } 
        }
      })
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

`this.data` no es un array, es un objeto literal, de ahí viene el mensaje de error.

`Math.max(valor1, valor2, ...valorN)` calcula el máximo entre valor1, valor2, ...valorN, es decir que haciendo solo el `.map` y usando el destructuring ya estaría, los primeros se pueden extraer con `.slice`

```js
const act = [{dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '1'},
    {dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '2'},
    {dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '3'},
    {dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '4'},
    {dateTime: '2021-08-16', value: '5'}];
    
const primeros_3 = act.slice(0,3);// <-- el index 3 no se incluye 
    
const maxValue = Math.max(...primeros_3.map(e=>e.value));

console.log(maxValue);
```